# Mapping to a function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I am relatively new to react and I am trying to map a list of locations to the google maps API. I cant figure out how to pass each argument to the function for the google API. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
export class Mapping extends React.Component {

  state = {
    zoom: 1,
  }

  render() {

    Geocode.fromAddress("Eiffel Tower").then(
      response => {
        const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
        console.log(lat, lng);
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );

    return (
      <div>
      <Map className="Map" center={[47, -29]} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"
        />
        {this.fromAddress}
        {data.features.map((loc, i) => 
          <Marker key={i} position={[
            loc.geometry.coordinates[0],
            loc.geometry.coordinates[1]
          ]}/>
          )}
      </Map>
    </div>
    )
  }
} 

export default Mapping;
```

Comment: Don't call API in render function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to place `Geocode.fromAddress` call into [`componentDidMount` method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount), this way once location is resolved and saved into [`state`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), component gets re-rendered.

Here is an example which demonstrates how to display a marker which location is determined from  `Geocode.fromAddress` method:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    position: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    Geocode.fromAddress("Eiffel Tower").then(
      response => {
        this.setState({position : response.results[0].geometry.location})
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Map center={[48.8583736, 2.2922926]} zoom={17}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        {this.state.position && <Marker position={this.state.position} />}
      </Map>
    );
  }
}
```